# How do I update a number from a reference date in a different table in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I want to be able to update the number of holdings for a particular stock I have with reference to a transaction sheet. So in one table, I would have the date that I bought and the amount I bought on that day. Then in another table, it would reference the date of the transaction, index the row of that date and then update the number I have bought to the correct number. I know how to return the row number for a search value (using =match function), but then I don't know how to update a formula based on its row.

[image: Here's an image of what I mean]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. I agree with @player0 here: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60837850/edit) your own question to rephrase it.

Comment: @DaemonPainter I have updated the image with rows because I forgot to add that. I want to update the function in column G based on the row number found by the match function. I myself don't really know how to put it in words...

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Can you show the function you are using?

Comment: @player0 Here - I made a mock-up of what I'm trying to do in this [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I7LeACZguaifStq7D6ZIp0p2TyCniJmiLdEjZD2SiXg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Jescanellas I don't have any functions - I'm trying to find out how I would make a function for that. You can check on the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I7LeACZguaifStq7D6ZIp0p2TyCniJmiLdEjZD2SiXg/edit?usp=sharing) to maybe help with understanding :)

Comment: still no idea what formula you seek and where in which cell you want that formula

Answer (score 2):

H3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,IF(B3:B="BUY", -1, 1)*F3:F*D3:D))
```

I3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(MATCH(A3:A, $M:$M, 0)))
```

O2:

```
={"Amount"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(M3:M, A3:G, 7, 1)))}
```

P2:

```
={"Average price"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(M3:M, A3:G, 5, 1)))}
```

J2:

```
={"Close"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A5, M3:N, 2, 0)))}
```

[image: 0]